# Error in creating tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a few tables in a new database, but when I try to create them it creates a couple of errors. I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The errors seem to be in the end of the code where I'm trying to add constraints for foreign keys. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Here's the code, it's meant to generate 3 tables with 1 table containing 2 foreign keys to the other tables with matching column names.

```
CREATE TABLE  Customers 
(
    CustomerID INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ContactName VarChar(50) NULL,
    Company VarChar(45) NULL,
    Phone VarChar(12) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Shippers 
(
    ShipperID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Company VarChar(45) NULL,
    Phone VarChar(12) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
    OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    OrderDate   DATETIME    NULL,
    ShippedDate DATETIME    NULL,
    ShipperID   INT NULL,
    Freight     DECIMAL NULL,
    CustomerID  INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Shippers
        FOREIGN KEY ShipperID
        REFERENCES Shippers(ShipperID)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Customers
        FOREIGN KEY CustomerID
        REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

And these are the errors I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
> Incorrect syntax near 'ShipperID'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
> Incorrect syntax near 'ACTION'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
> Incorrect syntax near 'ACTION'.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

The error messages point you to a couple of surplus commas, a missing comma and improper foreign key syntax due to missing parentheses.

This is the correct version:

```
CREATE TABLE  Customers (
    CustomerID  INT NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ContactName VarChar(50) NULL,
    Company VarChar(45) NULL,
    Phone       VarChar(12) NULL                         -- SURPLUS COMMA REMOVED
    )

CREATE TABLE Shippers (
    ShipperID   INT NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Company VarChar(45) NULL,
    Phone       VarChar(12) NULL                         -- SURPLUS COMMA REMOVED
    )


CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID     INT NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    OrderDate   DATETIME    NULL,
    ShippedDate DATETIME    NULL,
    ShipperID   INT NULL,
    Freight     DECIMAL NULL,
    CustomerID  INT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Shippers
            FOREIGN KEY (ShipperID)                         -- PARENTHESES ADDED
            REFERENCES Shippers(ShipperID)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
          ,                                                 -- COMMA ADDED
        CONSTRAINT fk_Orders_Customers
            FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)                        -- PARENTHESES ADDED
            REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    )
```